# Facebook login review for iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, facebook-login

I am developing mobile app for iOS.

Here is general scheme I want to implement:

1. User login into app using FB and confirm permissions for access to its personal data.
2. App transfers token to the server.
3. Server request personal data and processes it using .
4. Server return the final result to application.

I have few questions:

1. Is it permitted to request and store FB data on the server?
2. If so, how possible can I pass FB login review, given that FB requires specification how I am using permissions in mobile app? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review)
   Quote here: "Visibility: Data gained from the permission needs to be tied to a direct use."

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes Everything is possible just go through the developers console of the facebook all the steps are given in detail. You can post facebook data to your server